# What is the best Payment model to user

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment-processing, donations

I have to develop an android application for a charitable organisation that charges no admin fee in its use of the charitable funds. What ever is received from well wishers is used in charity to help the needy.

They would like to collect money from their well-wishers without paying any costs for payment processing.

I have looked at google in-app payment and they charge 30% whilst paypal charges 2.5%. The charity uses global-iris for their web based users.

I am trying to find a way that this organisation can get maximum money from its well wishers who use this app.

Can someone suggest me different solutions I can look at.

thanks

**EDIT** : I am planning on using Webview method and call the URI of the page we are using from the Website based donations.

Do I still have to pay Google anything if I go through this method or does this method fall foul of any Google play market regulations? Will I still have to pay Google using this method of collecting donations?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will fit the bill, but the answer may be to move outside of the transactional model.   All of these players make their money off the transaction.  That's understandable, it's what keeps them in business.  An out-of-business payment service is no use to you.  However, you could bend your model slightly to create a "ticket" based model.   Something like this:

- A donor opts to get a free "donor card".   THere is no charge for this card and thus no transaction fee.
- The donor can apply funds to the card outside of the apps or the website by simply sending funds to a well known address as often as desired, say $10/month via funds transfer or a check.
- Your apps and services draw on the funds as required or authorized

Key here is that there is no actual financial transaction for the draw.

Comment: Thanks - This could be used but then as a charity all the transactions need to be logged for audit purpose and they need to a proper tracking of where the money comes from and where it goes. In future we want to provide the donor ability to donate to a project and see what happened with their funds in that that project.